# Running Apache ActiveMQ Artemis, unable to login to web console due to IOException

Tags: activemq-artemis

(Windows, JDK8, and ARTEMIS_HOME set.)  I downloaded v2.5.0, created a broker, and ran it.

`artemis.cmd create broker1`, specify login info, `cd broker1` and `bin\artemis.cmd run`

(Understood that instance suggested not to be under ARTEMIS_HOME dir.)  The webconsole renders and I can access it via `localhost:8161/console`.  But trying to login, I get a Server Error on the web page, and the CLI shows

```
[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel] /console/auth/login/:java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: \login.config (No such file or directory)
```

The file `broker1/etc/login.config` does exist.  I have tried running from various directories and explicitly stating the configuration.

`cd broker1/bin`, `artemis.cmd run -- xml:artemis-ervice.xml`

But same issue.  Why can't this login.config be recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a bug in the `artemis.profile.cmd`. It's using this:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%ARTEMIS_ETC_INSTANCE%\login.config
```

But the `%ARTEMIS_ETC_INSTANCE%` variable is not defined.  I believe it should be using `%ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI%` instead.  Can you try this?  If that fixes the issue then I'll open a JIRA and sent a PR to get it fixed permanently.

Comment: I've since moved on to another project, but if @Nandish says it's good, I'll endorse as answer.  Is that against SO protocol?

Comment: As far as I understand, it's SO protocol (and common decency) to follow-up with the questions you ask rather than simply abandoning them when you no longer need the answer.

Comment: Confirming above worked for my scenario.  Hoorah for public decency!